# One's complement: Addition and Substraction

Tags: number-theory

My exam is coming up next week, but this has been bothering me for a while.

We have an assignment that says:

Add 45-58 in one's compliment.

So I did the conversion:

00101101 (45) 11000101 (-58)

The result: 11110010 (-13)

But the solution says that to get the result, I have to invert the -13: 00001101 - so the result, according to this task, is 13. I'm a bit confused, can anyone help me out? Cheers.

Comment: I am adding 45+(-58)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the solution means you should note that the MSB is $1$, so the result is negative.  You are then to write down a minus sign and invert the rest to find the (positive version of the) result.  After the inversion, you have $13$, which you write after the minus sign to get the result $-13$.  Certainly the correct answer is $-13$.  I don't think that is the way I would explain it, but it sounds consistent with the solution.